# Remove Everyone Permissions and add Authenticate Users permissions to Net Share folders

Tags: powershell

I have written a script to remove the **Everyone** permission and add the **Authenticated Users** permissions for the Net share.

But my script is removing it and adding the **Authenticated Users**, but it is only performing the action for the Root folders, not for the subfolder inside the root folder and I need to get that permission as an Inherited form parent.

And I just want to know like my script is excluding the shares which for (**'Remote Admin' ,"Default share' , 'Remote IPC' , 'Printer Drivers**'")

It would be great if someone can please help me achieve this...

```
$ScriptBlock = {
     "Executing on {0}" -f $env:COMPUTERNAME
     $ExclusionList = 'ADMIN\$','IPC\$' -join '|'
     $Shares = Get-SmbShare  | Where-Object -Property Name -notmatch $ExclusionList | Where-Object -Property Path -notmatch '^\w:\\$' 
     "Analyzing these shares...."
     $Shares
     foreach ($Share in $Shares) {    
         $Everyone = Get-SmbShareAccess $Share.Name | Where-Object -Property AccountName -eq Everyone
         if ($Everyone) {  
             Revoke-SmbShareAccess $Share.Name -AccountName 'Everyone' -Force
             Grant-SmbShareAccess $Share.Name -AccountName 'Authenticated Users' -AccessRight FullControl -Force
             "Share {0} has been updated." -f $Share.Name 
         }
     }
     "Complete"
 }
    
    
  $ComputerList = Get-Content "C:\users\a-lchandrakanthredd\Desktop\Test\Servers.txt"
        
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerList -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: share access and folder access are separate things. a share access define who can access something that is anywhere in the directory tree. Most often `Everyone` is fine on a `Share` and restricted permissions are granted on the folder. Now if you want subfolder to inherit from their parent, you can do it. `icacls d:\subfolder /inheritance:e` is an example to achieve it.

Comment: Can i use Icacls in my script when i am using the SMBshare function or parameter

Comment: Yes you can. Else to stay in the PowerShell `cmdlet` spirit you can use `Get-ACL` `Set-ACL`. But you need an understanding of access control entry (ACE) and .NET `FileSystemAccessRule` class.